# How can I receive the multi return values from DLL in VBA(Excel Visual Basic)?

Tags: excel, dll, vba

I'm currently trying to receive multiple return values from a DLL to Excel VBA.

This is my DLL code.

```cpp
double _stdcall pll_dll(double* datain0, double* datain1, double* dataout0, double* dataout1)
{
    dataout0[0] = datain0[0]+10;
    dataout1[0] = datain1[0]+10;

    return 0;
}
```

Then I want to give some value to the DLL by using the `datain0` and `datain1` and receive the `dataout0` and `dataout1` from the DLL to VBA.

This is my VBA code. Actually, I'm not familiar with Excel VBA.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function pll_dll Lib "F:\work\pll_dll\x64\Debug\pll_dll.dll" (ByRef x_in As Double, ByRef y_in As Double, ByRef x_out As Double, ByRef y_out As Double) As Double

Dim Error As Integer
Dim dat0 As Double
Dim dat1 As Double
Dim dat2 As Double
Dim dat3 As Double

  
Function pll_dll_excel(data0 As Double, data1 As Double, data2 As Double, data3 As Double) As Double
    pll_dll_excel = pll_dll(data0, data1, data2, data3)
End Function

Sub useSquareInVBA()
    MsgBox pll_dll_excel(3, 4, Cells(5, 5), Cells(6, 6))
End Sub
```

How do I have to make the function which is what I want to give `datain0=3`, `datain1=4` and receive the `dataout0` and `dataout1` values?

## Edit.

I've got some clue. and I've update my code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function pll_dll Lib "F:\work\pll_dll\x64\Debug\pll_dll.dll" (ByRef x_in As Double, ByRef y_in As Double, ByRef x_out As Double, ByRef y_out As Double) As Double

Dim Error As Integer
Dim dat0 As Double
Dim dat1 As Double
Dim dat2 As Double
Dim dat3 As Double
Dim d1 As Double
Dim d2 As Double


Function pll_dll_excel(data2 As Double, data3 As Double) As Double
    pll_dll_excel = pll_dll(3, 4, data2, data3)
    Cells(5, 5).Value = d1
    Cells(6, 6).Value = d2
End Function

Sub useSquareInVBA() ' Here is the start 
    MsgBox pll_dll_excel(d1, d2)
End Sub
```

Is this correct to receive the result value from the DLL?

## Edit2

```
Function pll_dll_excel(data1 As Double, data2 As Double, data3 As Double, data4 As Double) As Double
    pll_dll_excel = pll_dll(data1, data2, data3, data4)
    
End Function

Sub useSquareInVBA()
    MsgBox pll_dll_excel(3, 4, d1, d2)
    Cells(5, 5).Value = d1
    Cells(6, 6).Value = d2
End Sub
```

Is this correct?

Comment: `Is this correct` - no, it's not. You're passing `data2` and `data3` to the function, you should read the result from them, not from some unrelated `d1` and `d2`. Relying on the fact that `d1` and `d2` are in fact `data2` and `data3` (because they were passed this way to `pll_dll_excel` by the calling code) is one the most horrible and twisted side effects imaginable.

Comment: @GSerg I want to fix the above code, but I didn't get it exactly, so Can you fix the code? i'm not sure, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Read back from `data2` and `data3` as opposed to `d1` and `d2`, like I said above. Do you have any experience in programming in general, putting aside VBA specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dim d1 as double, d2 as double

pll_dll 3, 4, d1, d2

cells(5,5).value = d1
cells(6,6).value = d2
```

You've correctly `Declare`d a function that accepts four `Double`s `ByRef`. Now you are passing four numbers to it. It will put the result into `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: Thanks I feel like understand But can you let me know more detail? because I can't get it exactly. so can you help me a little bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure what else to explain. You've correctly `Declare`d a function that accepts four `Double`s `ByRef`. Now you are passing four numbers to it. It will put the result into `d1` and `d2` like one would expect.